# Sending a text with an editText is received in white in a TextView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm making an app but in this I need to put a username everything is fine, it does not give me any error but in the activity of "register user name" is just fine but in the following activity to save the text of that EditText does not go where it should, it goes blank I do not know what's happening

This is the class, to register the username

```
   public class UsernameRegiserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonRegisterAnonymous, buttonRegisterAUsername;
    private EditText getAUsernameToRegister;
    private User mUser;

    private Post mPost;
    private PostMemes mPostMemes;
    private PostCreativo mPostCreativo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_username_regiser);


       init();
    }

    private void init() {
        buttonRegisterAnonymous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegisterAsAnonymous);
        buttonRegisterAUsername = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister_aUsername);
        getAUsernameToRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_registerUsername);
        //==============================================================================

        mUser = new User();
        buttonRegisterAUsername.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nombre = getAUsernameToRegister.getText().toString();


                mUser.setUsername(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replaceAll(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail(), nombre));
                mUser.setUser(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replaceAll(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail(), nombre));

                startActivity(new Intent(UsernameRegiserActivity.this, LogInActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }
```

And in this fragment receives the name that has been placed in the editText

the relevant code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);
   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
   mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fabM);
   mUser = new User();

   return mRootView;
   }

   PopulateViewHolder...
   viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView.setText(mUser.getUser());
   if(viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView == null){
        viewHolder.postOwnerUsernameTextView.setText("Anonymous");
      }
```

the model class:

```
 public class User implements Serializable{
    private String user;
    private String email;
    private String Uid;
    private String username;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User(String user, String email, String uid, String username) {
        this.user = user;
        this.email = email;
        Uid = uid;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getUid() {
        return Uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        Uid = uid;
    }
}
```

and the utils that i use

```
public static DatabaseReference getUserRef(String email) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.USERS_KEYS)
            .child(email);
}
public static FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
}
```

the user is created with this method

```
 auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Sorry for my spelling and thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Another Activity you create a new model class once again. That's why your editTank gone Blank. Let try this solution to transfer data between 2 class

make new interface class call `TransferData`

```
public interface TransferData{
    void onTransferDataListener(String text);
}
```

Inside your activity let initial `TransferData`

```
public TransferData mTransferDataListener;
 public void setTransferData(TransferData listener) {
        this.mTransferDataListener= listener;
    }
//whenever your make a new String from EditText, put it in this function
mTransferDataListener.onTransferDataListener(yourText);
```

Finally, in your class that you want to get Data, you just need to implement `TransferData` class, don't forget add this function to initial the receiver

```
 //I call this function from my activity 
  mActivity.setTransferData(this);
```

after implement `TransferData` class, android studio will automatically add this override to receive the data

```
 @Override
    public void onTransferDataListener(String text) {
       //do what ever you want with your String text here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @TanHieu i try this now

Comment: @TanHieu i dont understand this  `mActivity.setGPSLocationListener(this);`

Comment: @TanHeiu can you see my answer.. its ok?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I'm in my activity, it's a dialog which sends the strings to a fragment

In that dialogue could do this?

UsernameRegisterClass:

```
  Public class UsernameRegister
  TransferData mTransferData;
  EditText mEditText;
  Public void setmTransferData (TransferData lisenter) { This.mTransferData = lisenter;}

    OnCreate (

   MTransferData.onTransferDataLisenter (mEditText.getText.toString ());
```

Dialog class:

```
 DialogClass.setTransferData (this); @Override Public void onTransferDataListener (String text) { MPost.setUsermae (text) // I think I get the text here}

Private void sendPost () {

   MPost.getUsername ();

  // is the code okay?
  }
```